# Total de perguntas sem respostas em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Na página principal, ao clicar em 'Sem Resposta', a página seguinte exibe o total de perguntas com um rótulo contendo texto não traduzido do inglês, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]